# initiate an event after a script already exist

Tags: javascript, events

on this page: [https://cesmeglise.org/recherche-dans-la-bible/)](https://cesmeglise.org/recherche-dans-la-bible)

I try to initiate an event after another script:

My script try to 'alert button' on click button

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    
    if(document.querySelectorAll("button")===e.target) {
alert('button');
    }
 
}, false);
```

exemple on the page button called "Verset Aléatoire" nothing happens

with your help i try this

```js
var i,dots;
dots =  document.getElementsByClassName('button');
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    for (i=0; i<dots.length; i++){
    if(document.querySelectorAll("button")[i]===e.target) {
alert('button');
    }
 }
}, false);
```

nothings happens

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` (similar to an Array). Does `document.querySelectorAll("button")[0]===e.target` work for your case?

Comment: @Kaddath no nothing

Comment: Then it may be a reference problem, in JS `{ a: 1 } !== { a: 1 }` because equality is tested on the reference of the object and 2 object created separately have a different reference even if the content is the same. You should try k90mirzaei's answer: give your button a unique id and try to test `if('yourUniqueID'===e.target.id) {`

Answer (score 0):

You're not selecting the exact element what you need is to use an id for your button and then use a selector like `document.getElementById('id')`

Answer (score 0):

[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList so you cannot check for equivalence with e.target. The code in your edit also is incorrect because you don't have any elements of class 'button'. Try the following instead. Although you still have the problem that if you click on the text inside the button, e.target is a `<span>` element. To [add text to a button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp), you should not need to add an interior `<span>`.

```
const buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button'));
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if(buttons.includes(e.target)) {
        alert('button');
    }
});
```

Comment: i modify the code with your help nothing happens

Comment: I've updated my answer after trying a few things in DevTools console on your linked page.

Answer (score 0):

@evces

I understand that I am not answering my question exactly.
but I think that there are several answers.

the really problem was to create (on the page) a scroll (http://jsfiddle.net/ryXFt/3/)to "Voici le résultat de votre recherche" when "on click" on button of bible search.

the code here: work on the page,

```js
//Begin Function scroll to endpoint "Voici le résultat de votre recherche"

    var translate = function(){
        $("button").click(function(event){ 
            $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#bibleSuperSearch_userFriendly2_Content_ResultsContainer").offset().top},
            'slow');
    });
    }

    //End function

    //Begin Function test input: not blanks or empty

    var testinput = function(){ 
    const input = document.getElementById("bibleSuperSearch_userFriendly2_Content_FormController_classicUserFriendly2_search");
    const name = input.value.trim();
          $("#bibleSuperSearch_userFriendly2_Content_FormController_classicUserFriendly2_button4").click(function(event){
            if (name.length == 0){
      alert('Veuillez remplir la case texte "Recherche:Entrez mot(s), phrase(s) ou expression(s):"');      
            };
    });
    }

    // End testinput

    //principal function
    var fctprincipal = function() {   
        document.readyState !== "complete" ? setTimeout(fctprincipal,11) : alert("loaded!"); // wait the page load
        $(document).ready(function(){
        testinput();
        translate();
      });
    }
// End principal function
    fctprincipal();
```